# How to change packet before sending it to network card

Tags: packet

I want to test packet manipulation at the driver level. I am supposed to change the existing driver code if required. The NIC is Realtek 8101E.

I have seen the flow of the driver and want to add my own data into the packet just before it sends it over the network. So as far I have read the source, just before the NIC takes ownership of the packet.

The reason I need to modify the driver code is because later on I may need to use other hardware registers to fill new data.

1. Should the `xxx_xmit()` function be the right place to modify the send packet?
2. Will there be any other implications with directly adding my packet mangling code in the `xxx_xmit()` function?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can do it in xmit callback. but note that this callback runs in interrupt context(SOFTIRQ) so you can't do blocking operations
Second, any packet change in the xmit function should have a similar "undo" related code in the receive function
The best way to manipulate a packet is using network filter in upper layers

Comment: But can I access hardware registers in the netfilter hooks, for example If i have to use some hardware register to fill the extra data, can this be made to access in netfilter hooks (POST ROUTING).

Comment: no problem, use ioremap with the physical address and read/write for example : char *p=ioremap(ADDRESS,LEN); p[0]=0x200;

Comment: if you don't want to hard coded the address use a module parameter for it

Comment: how to use module parameter?

Comment: Declare a variable and use module_param macro look here for simple example: http://blog.discoversdk.com/simple-module-example/